# Order of divs in a nav bar with two sections

Tags: html, css

I have a nav bar on my site that is currently one color and I would like to make the left side of it (where the nav links are) to be one color and then the right bit, the same color as the background.

Do I need to have it broken up into two divs in order to do this?

Currently my footer is broken up in two sections and I have it set up like this:

```
<div id="footer">
<div id="footer_left">
<div id="footer_right">
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

I was thinking of making my nav bar like the above example, but in my footer, the div "footer" holds information in my css file. If I were to have a div for the nav called "nav" there would be no information for it in my CSS file which would probably be dumb. (I don't know.)

Currently I have my header set up like this in my html file:

```
<div id='nav'>
<ul id='navleft'>
</ul>
<div id='navright'>
</div>
</div>
```

Like I said, div 'nav' actually contains no information so this is probably wrong. Also, should I enclose my ul 'navleft' into a 'navleft' div and put the information about the styling in nav left? Or should I put that information in nav and override what I don't need on the right side with navright?

My questions may seem really dumb or maybe even confusing, but I am really confused. I have a CSS reference book, but it isn't of any help for this specific question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this you need to use the float attribute, like so:

HTML:

```
<div class="nav">
    <div class="left">
        content
    </div>
    <div class="right">
        content
    </div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
div.nav
{
    width: 900px;
}

div.left,
div.right
{
    display: block;
    float: left;
}

div.left
{
    width: 600px;
}

div.right
{
    width: 300px;
}

div.clear
{
    clear: both;
}
```

Note you need to have an element with a **clear** attribute at the end of a container that has floating elements. Also, you can obviously adjust the **width** values to meet your requirements.

Answer (score 1):

You are on the right track. You will need to float both of the inner divs so they will display in the same row. Be sure to specific the widths of each of the divs to prevent problems later.